# Can I stagger UpdatePanel updates in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a situation in which I select an account and I want to bring back its details. This is a single UpdatePanel round trip and its quite quick.

In addition, I need to bring back some transactional information which is from a much bigger table and takes a couple of seconds for the query to come back.

Ideally, I would like to put this into a second update panel and update this additional information once it has been received, but after the first update panel has updated i.e. the user sees:

1. Change account
2. See account details (almost instant)
3. See transactional info (2 seconds later)

The only way I can think of doing this is to use javascript to cause a SECOND postback once the account details have been retrieved to get the transaction information. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two asynchronous postbacks using UpdatePanels at once.
(Otherwise, the ViewState would get messed up)

However, you can make two "raw" AJAX requests (without UpdatePanels) at once, if you're willing to process the results yourself.